# Live validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, button

- I have a text box validation here. The error message will not come as an alert, instead it will get printed in the html div tag.

Html:

```
    <div id="error" style="position:absolute; left:auto; top:7px;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:auto; top:25px;">
    First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="requiredFields()"><div>
```

Javascript:

```
function requiredFields(){
    var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    if(fName == ""){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "First name field cannot be empty";
    }else if(lName == ""){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Last name field cannot be empty";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
        alert("successful");
    }
}
```

- On click of a button, am printing the error message.
- My question is, is there any live validation in javascript?
- I mean, at first the error message should come at, button on click, and the time user enters value into text box, if first name text box has any value, i need to clear the error message without clicking the button again.

just check my link and help me.. http://jsfiddle.net/GACKm/

Comment: Here's a [somewhat complex example](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/CMmDF/) (using jQuery), but if you look at the event handling and function that is called on `submit`, more or less you just need to put your message part into a function that can be called both by your submit and at the end of the validation function, and then use `blur` or `change` to fire the event on each required field.

Comment: @Rachel take a look at my answer I have tested it and its working ,I have even provided jsfiddle for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GACKm/1/)

**//Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var oneTimeMsgClikced = false;
    function requiredFields() {
        var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var lName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        if (fName == "") {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "First name field cannot be empty";
            oneTimeMsgClikced = false;
        } else if (lName == "") {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Last name field cannot be empty";
            oneTimeMsgClikced = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
            if (oneTimeMsgClikced == false) {
                alert("successful");
                oneTimeMsgClikced = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**//html code**

```
<body>
    <div id="error" style="position: absolute; left: auto; top: 7px;">
        Errors here
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: auto; top: 25px;">
        First name:
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onblur="requiredFields()" />
        <br />
        Last name:
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" onblur="requiredFields()"/>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="requiredFields()" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses some approaches that are more modern than inline event handlers (e.g., `onchange=""`). This is driven by `data-` attributes, as you will see, and although it is not currently configured to handle anything other than an `input[type=text]` right now, it could be expanded to work with `select`s, `textarea`s, etc.

What is below makes no pretenses to work with IE8 and lower, due to those versions using `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener` to setup the event handlers. Again, this could be worked in, but it does work in all other modern browsers. It should work in IE9, although that is untested.

It may look like a lot going on, but take a look at it and see if you can work out how it operates. Feel free to ask me any questions you like, as well.

Here is a fiddle (tested in Chrome and Firefox):

http://jsfiddle.net/ndXTb/

**HTML**

```
<aside>
    <ol id="errors"></ol>
</aside>
<section id="signup">
    <form action="#">
        <p>
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="required" 
                       data-validate-error="First name may not be empty."
                       data-error-sort="0"/>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" class="required" 
                       data-validate-error="Last name may not be empty."
                       data-error-sort="1"/>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="addr1">Address 1:</label>
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="addr1" name="addr1" class="required" 
                       data-validate-error="Address may not be empty."
                       data-error-sort="2"/>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="addr2">Address 2:</label>
            <span><input type="text" id="addr2" name="addr2"/></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="city">City:</label>
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="required" 
                       data-validate-error="City may not be empty."
                       data-error-sort="3"/>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="state">State:</label>
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="state" name="state" class="required" 
                       data-validate-error="State may not be empty."
                       data-error-sort="4"/>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span></span>
            <span style="text-align: right;">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </span>
        </p>
    </form>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#signup {
    display: table;
}
#signup form > p {
    display: table-row;
}
#signup p > label,
#signup p > span {
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}
#signup p > label {
    text-align: right;
    width: 150px;
}
.validationerror input {
    border: 1px solid #a00;
    background-color: #ffd;
    padding: 2px 1px;
}
.validationerror:after {
    content: '!';
}
```

**Javascript**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function init(){
    var signup = document.getElementById('signup'),
        fields = signup.getElementsByClassName('required'),
        errors = document.getElementById('errors'),
        error = '<li>{error}</li>',
        submitted = false,
        errorlog = [],
        index = 0,
        field,
        focusin;

    signup.addEventListener('submit', validateform);

    while (field = fields[index++]) {
        field.addEventListener('blur', validatefield);
        field.addEventListener('keyup', validatefield);
    }

    function validatefield() {
        var message = this.dataset['validateError'],
            sort = this.dataset['errorSort'],
            parent = this.parentNode;

        if (this.value === '' && (message && sort)) {
            errorlog[sort] = error.replace('{error}', message);
            parent.className += ' validationerror';

            if (!focusin) {
                focusin = this;
            }
        } else if (this.value !== '' && (message && sort)) {
            delete errorlog[sort];

            parent.className = parent.className.replace('validationerror', '');

            if (focusin == this) {
                focusin = null;
            }
        }

        if (!submitted) {
            isvalid();
        }
    }

    function validateform(event) {
        index = 0;
        errorlog = [];
        focusin = null;

        submitted = true;

        while (field = fields[index++]) {
            callevt(field, 'focus');
            callevt(field, 'blur');
        }

        submitted = false;

        if (!isvalid()) {
            if (focusin) {
                focusin.focus();
            }

            focusin = null;

            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function isvalid() {
        errors.innerHTML = '';

        if (errorlog.length) {
            errors.innerHTML = errorlog.join('');

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function callevt(el, type) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');

        evt.initEvent(type, true, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [onBlur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) and [onKeyUp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)

Comment: check the link.. http://jsfiddle.net/GACKm/  how to use onBlur and onKeyup in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use onclick event handler for Submit.

For live validation you can use onblur, insert it into the input box. This will validate the input every time you move away from the input field.

Comment: can you check the link.. http://jsfiddle.net/GACKm/   on click event handler for button is necessary..

Comment: @Rachel - Bazinga777 means that you need to handle the `form`s `submit` event, not the `input[type=submit]`'s click event. That will not stop the `form` from submitting (the `onclick`), which is what is meant here. Your fiddle does not feature a `form` element around the `input[type=submit]`, hence you don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<script>
function checkFName()
{
    fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    if(fName == ""){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "First name field cannot be empty";
        document.getElementById("fname").focus;
        return false;
    }
}

function checkLName()
{
    lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    if(lname == ""){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Last name field cannot be empty";
        document.getElementById("lname").focus;
        return false;
    }
}
</script>


<div id="error" style="position:absolute; left:auto; top:7px;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:auto; top:25px;">
    First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onchange="checkFName();"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" onchange="checkLName();"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><div>
```

Hope this will help