# Disable then enable submit button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to validate a form by using Ajax.I check each row with this code :
Data is pass to formValidate.php file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(event){
    stuId= $("input[name='stuId']").val();
    stuName= $("input[name='stuName']").val();
    stuDoB= $("input[name='stuDoB']").val();
    stuAdd= $("input[name='stuAdd']").val();

    $.get("formValidate.php?stuId="+stuId,function(data){
        $(".formCheck:eq(0) span").text(data);
        $.get("formValidate.php?stuName="+stuName,function(data){
            $(".formCheck:eq(1) span").text(data);
                $.get("formValidate.php?stuDoB="+stuDoB,function(data){
                $(".formCheck:eq(2) span").text(data);
                $.get("formValidate.php?stuAdd="+stuAdd,function(data){
                    $(".formCheck:eq(3) span").text(data);
                });
            });
        });
    });
    event.preventDefault(); 
    for(var i=0;i<=3;i++)   {
        var a= $(".formCheck:eq("+i+") span").text();
        if(!a)  
            break;
        if(i==3)
            $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
    }
       });
    });
```

In every check I will disable the submit button.
In the end if any validate span has any text,the submit wont be bind back;
The problem is the first time I click submit button with blank field,it's ok,it show the validate.But when I click submit button again,the form is submitted when field is still blank.
What is my problem ? Please help me out ?

Comment: If you are dealing with a simple form [whose markup you should provide as well], making a validation call per row is totally avoidable. Validate the form client side, then provide server with validation rules as well.

Comment: Have you tried triggering on click event for the submit button instead of submit evt?

Comment: But I have to check the input with such as there is no same data in the database,I think Ajax is fine with this
@jtheman  my form have a button type=submit

Comment: @jtheman - You have to stop the form `submit` event, so detecting the `click` on the button won't do anything. Duc, are you trying to progress, one field to the next after each is "validated" on the server? Keep in mind, you *must* validate all over again on the server; what you're doing on the client is merely for the ease of the user sitting at the computer, but cannot be trusted.

Comment: sequence of AJAX makes no sense, if any of the items before last fail nothing is done about it

Comment: @Jared yes you are right,I have to check it all over,I'' fix that.But leave it later,can you tell me why I got the problem above ?
charli : ye it may but I have to make sure it wont be :D

Comment: Because that's a [really unreliable way](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/EzQsX/) determine if your form has passed any test. Take a look at [this answer I wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15273623/451969) (no jQuery used, but you get the point). Attach the async validation calls to the *elements*, and then trigger each field's validation event (like `blur.validation` or `change.validate`, which is called event namespacing) when the form is submitted. Toggle a class like `notvalidated` based on the response from the script (*don't* do the *is this element sorta empty* like you are).

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all this validation, you are using really should be just the "**cherry on a pie**". And help you achieve more user-friendly form. You really should consider to use some predefined form-checking libraries. And last but not least, always validate on server side.

To explain what is wrong, please look at this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JLySr/

Every little space in the text will allow/disallow you to pass validation.
So after first validation ajax will probably return a space or something like that...
You might a sightly improve this by triming the text:

```
var a= $(".formCheck:eq("+i+") span").text().trim();
```

But still this is **NOT** a real validation. As you might know its really pretty easy to remove part of webpage on client side.