# Javascript Namespace + onchange = impossible?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I am using a namespace for my javascript code, and I *think* I have hit a brick wall with a *onchange* attribute for a select element.  When I attempt to call a function with (or without) my namespace the error console is reporting that the function is not found.

```
var MYNS = {}; //namespace
MYNS.modifySearchPage = function () {
    ....
    var eSelect = document.createElement("select")
    .....
    eSelect.setAttribute('onchange', 'MYNS.handleChange(this)');
    .....
    //set up the options (value, textcontent, eSelect.appendChild(theOption)
    ...
    // add the eSelect to the DOM
}
MYNS.handleChange = function (select) {
    //parse the select options
}
```

The result I get in the console when I select an item from the dropdown list is:
   `Uncaught ReferenceError: MYNS is not defined`

I have attempted to add the namespace to the windows but that does not seem to help (and I'm not convinced that is a safe thing to do).

I have tried adding a onclick handler to the *select* element but obviously that is a bad idea as *select* does not handle onclicks.

Stripping the MYNS from both the call and function definition also didn't help.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
mwolfe

Comment: `MyNS.handleChange` should be `MYNS.handleChange` ?

Comment: That `'MYN.handleChange(this)'` is running that through `eval()`, which is unnecessary; just pass a reference to the function, or use event listeners, e.g., `eSelect.addEventListener('change', handleChange);` Take a look at [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15273623/451969), which demonstrates `addEventListener()`. Note, IE8< requires `attachEvent()`, which I grow tired of handling. If you need those browsers, you need to handle that difference.

Comment: Thanks @coouzzi/Dereck, spelling mistake.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/N9mzM/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use attributes to attach handlers - use properties:

```
eSelect.onchange = function() {
    MYNS.handleChange(this);
};
```

More generically you could also use the standard and more recommended `addEventListener`:

```
function changeHandler() {
    MYNS.handleChange(this);
}

if (eSelect.addEventListener) {
    eSelect.addEventListener('change', changeHandler, false);
} else if (eSelect.attachEvent)  {
    eSelect.attachEvent('onchange', changeHandler);  // fallback for IE
}
```

It's also worth noting that you can call

```
eSelect.addEventListener('change', MYNS.handleChange, false);
```

You will need to modify your callback though - the argument passed will be an event object and `this` inside the function will refer to the element that triggered the event.

Comment: No... [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)? `:(`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Added it.  I avoided it initially because there is always the IE caveat...

Comment: Ahhh... More better. `:)` (*Let's not mention the convoluted manner it it takes to `dispatchEvent()`.*)

Comment: Also, why do you have a pass-through and use it to pass `this`? You can reference it directly, `addEventListener('change', MYNS.handleChange)`

Comment: That would require a change to `handleChange` which takes the element as a parameter.  OP may want `this` in that function to refer to `MYNS`.  It's unclear based on the provided code and I don't often like rewriting code that I can't see.

Comment: Right. Who likes rewriting code they can't see. Infer maybe. I know I went a couple years "programming" in Javascript before I realized I was passing `this` as a parameter when it was there the whole time if I did it right (event attributes like this at the time). The only problem the code has then is the `MyNS`.

Comment: Thank you so much @JaredFarrish and Dennis.  The addEventListener is working great.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You just code a different word of wrong case `MyNS.handleChange`, it should be `MYNS.handleChange`. In JavaScript variables are case sensitive.