# Javascript select() value

Tags: javascript, forms, select, focus, numeric

I am sure this is super easy, but for some reason I just can't figure this one out.

I need to create a form on the page with the following fields and rules. If the user submits a form but the rules are broken for any field, the behavior listed must be done to advise the user. I am not allowed to use jQuery. Field01 & Field02 is one box. Field03 & Field04 is one box.

- Field01: "Username" - Rule01: Cannot be empty, Behavior01: Put focus on it using focus().
- Field02: "Username" - Rule02: Cannot be empty, Behavior02: Alert the user that "username is required".
- Field03: "Birthyear" - Rule03: Must be numeric, Behavior03: Select the value using select().
- Field04: "Birthyear" - Rule04: Must be between 1900 - 2012, Behaviour04: Turn the Birthyear text box background color to yellow.

This is what I have so far... Struggling with the Field03 & Field04.

Does anyone know how to approach this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="dawid_spamer_Assign01.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="div1">
            <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>       
            Birth Year: <input type="select" id="birthYear" name="birthYear"><br><br>
             <input type="submit"  value="Submit">

            </form></div>

        <div id="div2">
            <img src="cat.jpg"    id="im1" name="image1"/>
            <img src="dog.jpg"    id="im2" name="image2"/>
            <img src="fish.jpg"   id="im3" name="image3" class='double'/>
        </div></body></html>
```

JS in Separate file:

```
document.getElementById("username").focus(); // focus on text box 

function validateForm(){
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
if (x==""){
    alert("Username Required!");
            // focus on text box
    document.getElementById("username").focus();  
    return false; // validation failed
}else{
    return true; // validation success  
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer and fiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264501/live-validation-using-javascript/15273623#15273623) for a general outline of how to setup the validation process (sans jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementById("username").focus(); // focus on text box

function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Username Required!");
        // focus on text box
        document.getElementById("username").focus();
        return false; // validation failed
    }

    var dob = document.forms["myForm"]["birthYear"];
    var y = dob.value;
    if(!(/^\d+$/.test(y))){
        alert('must be numert');
        dob.select();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g7ntQ/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the BirthYear field must be highlighted if the value provided is not numeric. This can be accomplished using the [select() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_text_select.asp) provided by JavaScript.

Use the [isNaN() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to check if the value provided is numeric.